# compute column average based on conditions pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame with 3 columns and several rows that are near-duplicates of each other, except for one value. my goal is to merge those rows and create a new column and calculate avg of the distinct values.

here is an example:

```
names subject value
A       X      5
A       X      10
A       X      15
A       Y      17
A       Y      19
A       Y      11
B       P      7
B       P      9
B       P      15
B       P      18
B       Q      0
B       Q      13
B       Q      17
```

And here is what I would like:

```
names subject value  average
A       X      5    |   
A       X      10   |-> 30/3 = 10
A       X      15   |
A       Y      17   |
A       Y      19   |-> 47/3 = 15.67
A       Y      11   |
B       P      7    |
B       P      9    |-> 49/4 = 12.25
B       P      15   |
B       P      18   |
B       Q      0    |
B       Q      13   |-> 30/3 = 10
B       Q      17   |
```

Comment: Have you tried "groupby", e.g. `df.groupby(["names", "subject"]).mean().reset_index()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`.mean()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html), followed by rename column by [`.rename()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html), as follows:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['names', 'subject'], as_index=False)['value'].mean().rename({'value': 'average'}, axis=1)
```

Result:

```
print(df2)

  names subject    average
0     A       X  10.000000
1     A       Y  15.666667
2     B       P  12.250000
3     B       Q  10.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the index to be the names and then groupby the subject and apply the mean. This would give you the averages. Then you can add that column using list comprehension.

```
df['mean'] = [df.set_index('names').groupby('subject').mean()['value'][subject] for subject in df['subject'] ]
```